# In which book does the War of the Seven Spheres take place?

Tags: story-identification, marvel, comics, doctor-strange

Somewhere before the Midnight Sons take over and massacre the Dr. Strange Comic Arts, we see a mention of the War of the Seven Spheres. However, what actually happened and how is it not seen? Instead, we directly see a weary Dr. Strange returning to Earth and mentioning that it happened. In which book is the war depicted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Marvel Crossovers](http://marvelcrossovers.blogspot.com/2019/11/war-of-seven-spheres-1992-1993.html) gives a brief summary of the events leading up to the war.

> Doctor Strange has been using magic in the name of varies mystical
> beings over the years (such as Cyttorak, the Raggadorr, Munnopor,
> etc), calling upon their power to assist him in his role as Sorcerer
> Supreme. So he must owe them pretty big, right? Well, he doesn't see
> it that way. When the Vishanti ask for his help in fighting a 5000
> year magic war, Strange decides to go AWOL. But that doesn't come
> without consequences...

And identifies the following comics as being integral to understanding this event (along with a reading order)

> - Doctor Strange: Sorcerer Supreme Annual #2
> - Doctor Strange: Sorcerer Supreme #42
> - Silver Surfer #67
> - Doctor Strange: Sorcerer Supreme #43-47
> - Darkhold #3-7
> - Doctor Strange: Sorcerer Supreme #48-50

Answer (score 0):

The [War of the Seven Spheres](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/War_of_the_Seven_Spheres) was a major conflict in the magic community that involved most of the major wielders of magic in the Marvel universe.
It was a predestined cyclical conflict among powers and mystic principalities of the mystic planes. In this war, many of the ancient treaties and arrangements between the deities are annulled. As a result, the laws of magic are subject to revision and at times can be circumvented.

The war began in Secret Defenders #25 in January 1995 and ended in July the same year in Doctor Strange, Sorcerer Supreme #80.